# mysql partitioning with unix_timestamp from variable

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Given this :

```
delimiter //
create procedure setup()
begin
  declare d datetime;
  set d = rounddate(now());

  create table s_time (req_id int not null,
                       ser_id int not null,
                       hel_id int not null,
                       posted int unsigned not null,
                       completed int unsigned not null default 0
                      )
  partition by range (completed) (partition p0 values less than ( unix_timestamp(d) ),
                                  partition p1 values less than ( unix_timestamp(d + interval 1 day) )
                                 );
end//
```

I get :

`ERROR 1064 (42000) : Constant, random, or timezone-dependent expression in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed`

Is there any way to get this to work, or do I have to use a hard-coded string for the input. ie use : `unix_timestamp('2012-07-07 00:00:00')`

Comment: Is your `s_time` table supposed to survive the end of your procedure? Also, are you expecting the partitions to be reorganised aotomatically? In other words: right now, `p0` partition contains all records up to right now. In 24hs from now, will `p0` be expected to contain all records up to "in 24hrs from now"?

Comment: This procedure is just to auto setup the table. The table will be used as a rolling partition. After 24 hrs the first partition will be deleted and another one will be added.I was wondering if there is a way not to hardcode the two first partitions. I guess I could make another procedure that does the first two initial rolls and call that after the create of the table with hardcoded values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep the solution in full sql this is what I have found.

```
delimiter //
create procedure setup()
begin
  declare d, d2 int;
  set d = unix_timestamp();
  set d2 = unix_timestamp(now() + interval 1 day);

  create table s_time (req_id int not null,
                       ser_id int not null,
                       hel_id int not null,
                       posted int unsigned not null,
                       completed int unsigned not null default 0
                      );

  SET @stmt = concat('alter table s_time PARTITION BY RANGE (completed) (
                      partition p0 values less than (', d, '),
                      partition p1 values less than (', d2, '))');
  PREPARE pStmt FROM @stmt;
  EXECUTE pStmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE pStmt;

end//
delimiter ;
call setup();
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this not working is not so clear, I suspect a bug either in the documentation or in the error message. The error you are receiving is inappropriate, in my opinion.

According to [the manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html)

> The following constructs are not permitted in partitioning
>   expressions:
>
> - Stored procedures, stored functions, UDFs, or plugins.
> - **Declared variables** or user variables.

This explains why your table definition fails.

Now, how to get rid of your variable? If you try to remove the declared variable from the partition definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE s_time (
    completed INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( completed  ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )
);
```

you will get the same error. However, the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html) states:

> It is also possible to use an expression in VALUES LESS THAN clauses.
>   However, MySQL must be able to **evaluate the expression's return value
>   as part of a LESS THAN (<) comparison**.

According to this definition, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` should be a valid expression. This sentence from the manual is inaccurate to say the least. I am very curious to see if someone else could provide another understanding.

Now, looking at the error message, if you consider the `LESS THAN` clause as a part of the "partitioning function", then the error message starts making sense:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) : Constant, **random**, or timezone-dependent expression in
>   (sub)partitioning function *or in LESS THAN clause* are not allowed

By "random", they also mean *non-deterministic*, which the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function is by definition.

To achieve what you are trying to do, I see no other solution but using an external script to generate the suitable `ALTER TABLE` command.

1) Create your initial table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE s_time (
    req_id INT NOT NULL,
    ser_id INT NOT NULL,
    hel_id INT NOT NULL,
    posted INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    completed INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) PARTITION BY RANGE (completed) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1)
);
```

2) [Reorganise the partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html) every now and then (e.g. with PHP):

```php
<?php
    $query = 
        "ALTER TABLE s_time REORGANIZE PARTITION p0, p1 INTO (
            PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ($today),
            PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ($tomorrow)
        )";
```

See the [proof of concept here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11f35).