# Will Mysql Partitioning auto-add a new partition?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I am setting up partitions to separate very large datasets by quarter. Is there a way to have  Mysql automatically create a new partition each quarter or do I have to pre-allocate them?

What are best practices for this? Perhaps to just make all the partitions for the next few years and forget about it? Or run a quarterly cron?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: mysql creates partitions based on an expression. that implies it'll auto-create new partitions automatically if the result of a partition calculation returns a value that hasn't previously been used for a partition. e.g. `PARTITION BY YEAR(datefield)` would create a new partition every year.

Comment: @MarcB: Are you thinking of [`HASH` Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning-hash.html), e.g. `PARTITION BY HASH(YEAR(datefield))`?

Comment: MarcB yes. Since the partition keys must also be in EVERY UNIQUE key, I need to combing row_id (auto inc) with a YEAR(timestamp). But my data is doubling every year so yearly might not be the best answer. I'd really like to partition every 50,000,000 records or so. I have over 600M records now.   My problem is that the row_id is not in every unique key and would mess up my queries if it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several partitioning methods in MySQL, but they all reduce to spreading data over a *predetermined* number of partitions ([see syntax here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-types.html)).

You can, however, setup a cron job or use the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) to add new partitions as time passes.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11208964/1446005) offers a nice procedure that could be triggered at regular intervals to achieve this effect. Modifying the procedure so that it partitions by year (instead of days) seems to be straightforward.