# auto create partition on a table based on date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have created a partition on one of the table, and I wanted it to automatically create the partitions based on the date.

Is there any possibility of creating partitions automatically as soon as data logged into the table with dates?

Comment: Can check this link [Auto create partition procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163237/mysql-partitioning-with-unix-timestamp-from-variable/11208964#11208964)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

It may help someone else.

> Create Stored procedure which will take date as a input and build a partition to that table 
>   and create an event in MySQL which will run a procedure based on the scheduled time.